# Issues in interfacing relay with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, relay

I want to control AC bulb with Arduino, 5v-relay.
My connections are

[image]

My code is

```c
#define RELAY1  7

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(RELAY1, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
  digitalWrite(RELAY1,LOW); // Turns ON Relays 1
  Serial.println("Light OFF");
  delay(15000); // Wait 5 seconds
  digitalWrite(RELAY1,HIGH); // Turns Relay Off
  Serial.println("Light ON");
  delay(20000);
}
```

- Red LED is on according to AC bulb.
- Power LED (Green colored one) is also on as I have given 5v supply from Arduino.

The issues are

1. Bulb is not following the delay given in the code. The output for the above code is 20sec ON - 15sec OFF -20sec ON - 15sec OFF- 20sec ON -15sec OFF -  1sec ON - 20sec ON - 15sec OFF etc. means apart from 20,15 sec duration there is a duration of 1sec is coming in between as noise. What might be the reason?
2. On monitor also, only first 3 actions are getting printed after that no printing is observed.

==>The relay I am using is:

[image]

Comment: What relay board are you using? Do you hear the relay clicking?

Comment: yes I can here the relay clicking.!

Comment: As Gerben says, please state the relay part number, and give a link to it. Are you sure you connected Vcc on the relay to the +5 V pin on the Arduino?

Comment: @Nick, I dont have link to relay. But I have uploaded the relay picture in the question it self.  I am sure that 5v pin on Arduino connected to 5v pin on the relay.

Comment: There are two transistors there (the small black things with are sort-of a semicircle). Please read the part number and post that.

Comment: Part no on the transistor is "CTBC  5478  JS"

Comment: Are there any resistors (or parts of any kind) on the back of the board? Can you photograph that please?

Comment: Also please measure what voltage is on the 5V pin (with your multimeter) once the sketch is running. Is it 5V? Or something somewhat lower?

Comment: There is nothing on the back of the board except the metal connections.

Comment: You may want to add capacitor to help shore up your 5v.

Answer (score 1):

what i would do is test the parts one by one.
so first look if you're signal is good by attaching a led to it.
then test you're relay with 5v.

now you should know what the problem is the arduino or the relay

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good, however Try a different relay, and double check your AC side and be sure the bulb voltage is correct for the AC and the bulb is OK.

You may have a power shortage from your USB or however you are powering it.  If you can monitor the 5VDC and be sure it is stable.

Good Luck